# Birch interior door sealer?

Tags: physical-protection

I recently bought beautiful hollow core paint grade birch skin interior doors. I do not want to paint or add a gloss/sheen to them. I want to maintain the colour, texture and authenticity of the wood as much as possible but I need to protect them from future wear and tear. What are my options for sealing them?

Comment: A water born poly would leave the doors the closest to there original color, I prefer the oil based it ascents the grain better.

Comment: Check https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/finishing for previous Q&A, as this is almost certainly discussed previously.

Comment: @jdv, I thought so too (I checked first and it is, in general) but the specifics of the Question warrant its own Answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use pretty much any finish on a door, depending on the look you desire and what you want to work with. Doors don't really need a highly protective finish unless there are young kids in the house.

> I do not want to paint **or add a gloss/sheen** to them.

But the part in bold is the key thing here, since you don't want to add gloss this rules out many options immediately since the majority of finishes increase shine. Although you can matt down any gloss finish you probably don't want to mess around with that on a project of this size and for consistency and ease of use you should just go with a matt finish.

Oil-based varnishes, polyurethanes in particular, generally give superior protection and they do most to highlight the natural grain structure or figure in the wood of all finish types, but they add a significant amount of yellow/amber colouring to pale woods. This will also increase over time as all oil finishes 'yellow' (go more amber to be more precise).

Waterbased finishes dry "water white" (do note they are milky in the container however) and will change the look of wood minimally. The matt versions in particular are rather famous for virtually leaving wood looking unchanged since there's little or no change in surface gloss. If you're in the US something from General Finishes would be a good choice that is likely to be available locally.

**Note:** it's important to bear in mind however that the wood itself will change colour slightly over time and that you can't prevent this*. Birch, maple and other pale or whitish woods all shift colour slightly towards tan. The change is slow and subtle so you won't really see it happening, but eventually you'll notice that your doors which were once quite pale are now more beige.

---

*Some finishes have UV inhibitors built in but they aren't UV-stable so the protection is never permanent.

Comment: It's somewhat ironic that the UV-inhibitors aren't UV-stable.

Comment: @FreeMan, I suppose so, but they work by absorbing UV which is energetic, and this ultimately leads to them being destroyed. There are some finishes that claim to provide permanent UV protection, but even five years of full protection, trailing off after that..... you don't have to be a cynic to question the use of the word "permanent".

Comment: It makes sense, it's just ironic. ;)

Comment: Thank you so much for a concise, eloquent answer for this non woodworker. I shall try the water based and see how we get on. Thank you everyone. Sorry if this question has been asked before but as I’m new to this I wanted to double check.